# Did Virginia Woolf read The Yellow Wallpaper before publishing Mrs. Dalloway?

Tags: inspiration, virginia-woolf, charlotte-perkins-gilman, mrs-dalloway

In a recent discussion in an online literature course, someone thought that the young woman in Charlotte Perkins Gilman's [The Yellow Wallpaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Yellow_Wallpaper) and the character Septimus Warren Smith in Virginia Woolf's [Mrs. Dalloway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mrs_Dalloway) were both threatened by inactivity imposed on them by pompous medical men. This led to the question whether Virginia Woolf had read Charlotte Perkins Gilman's short story. Date-wise it is possible, since "The Yellow Wallpaper" was published in *The New England Magazine* in 1892, and *Mrs. Dalloway* was published in 1925. However, I'm not sure whether [The New England Magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_England_Magazine), which ceased publication in 1917, had enough circulation outside the USA, or whether the short story was sufficiently well-known to come to Woolf's notice.

So is there any evidence that Virginia Woolf read Charlotte Perkins Gilman's short story before 1925?